# Align two sibling divs (content and sidebar)?

Tags: css, html

I have the web site as attached below. I have two sibling elements (#content and ) and I would like to have my aside to be "completely" on the right (eliminate gaps that seen in the pic) and stick to the header (right now the navigation bar seems to be blocking that space).

Website:

[image]

Comment: Post your code so we have a [mcve] of the current layout with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Give the elements a parent and apply `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <main>content</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what does this do?

Comment: @nincs12 here is a visual guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/